# Export properties of a feature collection Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, features

I would like to export only the properties of a filtered feature collection, I made a try which is probably wrong because I'm not selecting the properties I want (area, FinalDate,Id,InitialDate ) and it generates a very big csv file. So the question is how to select only the properties I need?

```js
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('JRC/GWIS/GlobFire/v2/FinalPerimeters');

var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017')
                              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ECO_ID', 569));

// Filter the table geographically
var filtered = dataset.filterBounds(mask);
print('First ', filtered.first());

var visParams = {
  palette: ['f5ff64', 'b5ffb4', 'beeaff', 'ffc0e8', '8e8dff', 'adadad'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 600000000.0,
  opacity: 0.8,
};

// Visualization
//
var image = ee.Image().float().paint(filtered, 'area');
Map.centerObject(mask, 5);

Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'GlobFire Amazonas');
Map.addLayer(filtered, null, 'for Inspector', false);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a csv file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: filtered,
  description:'GlobFireChacoSeco',
  fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option on the Export function 'selectors' that lets you specify the ones you want (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-table-todrive):

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: filtered,
  description:'GlobFireChacoSeco',
  fileFormat: 'csv',
  selectors: ['area', 'FinalDate','Id','InitialDate'])
});
```